# Calculated Percentage Widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, percentage

What I basically have are two columns standing side by side on a percentage-based layout.  The left column is **always 175px wide**.  The right column is the **remainder of the available width**.  Of course, since the browser window can be resized and all, that right column's width changes.  Is there a Javascript or Jquery script that I could use to set the left column to 175px wide and then calculate the remainder of the browser's window width to apply to the right column?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very likely, but why javascript? Just use CSS.

Comment: I don't think that I can use CSS.  Because the width of the left column is fixed while the width of the right column changes, even the percentage of the right column is not constant...it changes depending on how wide the window is.

Comment: Please post your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple example to demonstrate the use of CSS (see working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxFFs/3/)):

```
<div id="columns" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="left_col" style="float:left;width:175px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black;">Left column</div>
    <div id="right_col" style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;">Remaining column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!  That's exactly what I was looking for!  I guess the trick is not to specify `float:right` for the dynamic-width div, and not to specify `display: inline` for either one of them.  Thanks, all!

Comment: Actually, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxFFs/3/) is better given your comments.

Answer (score 0):

can you use simple div / css?

```
<div id="columns">
    <div id="static_left" style="float:left;width:175px;"></div>
    <div id="remaining_right" style="float:left;"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely.  The columns themselves are divs contained within a larger div.

The issue with that setup, though, is that unless I explicitly assign a width to `#remaining_right`, the browsers automatically assume that `width: 100%` and knock `#remaining_right` down below `#static_left`.  This is both before and after I set them both to `display-inline`.

Of course, i could have done something wrong...

Comment: understood .. you'd still have an issue if the content of remaining_right was greater than 100% - 175 ... CSS3 would help, but not all browsers support it ..